# How can I make a diagonal div responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have a pricing table that contains a diagonal badge as shown in the image below. The pricing table is responsive and so is the badge. However, as I shrink the pricing table, the badge's right side "detaches" from the parent `div` (see image below). I followed [this code](https://codepen.io/nxworld/pen/oLdoWb), and I can't tell what I'm missing.

```css
.card-premium-category {
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 4px solid white;
  width: 85px;
  height: 85px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: -9%;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.card-premium-header {
  height: 128px;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.background-gradient-with-frog {
  background: red;
  background-size: 54% auto, cover;
  background-position: 115% 23%;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 600px;
  width: 90%;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

.ribbon {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

.ribbon span {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 268px;
  padding: 4px 0;
  background-color: white;
  color: #495057;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.ribbon-top-right {
  top: 0;
  right: -31px;
}

.ribbon-top-right span {
  left: -25px;
  top: 30px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-around text-center">
  <div class="premium-cards-wrapper col-12 mt-4">

    <!-- PRICING TABLE -->
    <div class="card-premium-container col-11 col-xs-11 col-sm-11 col-md-3 
             col-lg-3 mx-auto text-center space-right-left recommended">
      <div class="card-premium-category">
        <img src="#" class="super-reebit">
      </div>
      <div class="card-premium-body">
        <div class="box">
          <div class="ribbon ribbon-top-right"><span>Recomendado</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-premium-header background-gradient-with-frog">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /PRICING TABLE -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's my [codepen](https://codepen.io/paulamourad/pen/PoNPBqv).

This is what I need to achieve:

[image]

This is my issue:

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant code (in a snippet if possible, using the `[<>]` button in the editor). External links to CodePen etc are acceptable, but only *in addition* to having the code in the question itself - external links can change, break etc over time which makes the question invalid and unhelpful to other users.

Comment: @Johannes why you reopened a perfect duplicate?

Comment: @Paula Well, for what it's worth, the CodePen you tried to copy is not responsive insofar as the diagonal divs are concerned. The only "responsive" thing about that CodePen demo is that the whole element is centered in the screen. So it would make perfect sense that following that CodePen would produce the result you got.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Any particular reason that you set .box width to 90%? I changed .box width to 100% in your codepen and it looks ok.

Comment: If I set my `.box` to `width: 100%` it gets wider than it's parent.

Comment: Changing `.box { width: 90%; }` to `.box { width: 100%;}` doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @TylerH did you test in Paula's codepen? which browser you're using?

Comment: @BlueP Any browser would have no problem with a percentage value of the `width` property. I opened up her code snippet and looked there. In the CodePen, it does make a difference but an overcorrection difference; it expands the 45-deg div beyond the edge rather than pushing it to the edge of the main box div.

Comment: @TylerH I believe the OP had updated the codepen since I posted the answer. And it could be corrected by setting the .ribbon-top-right Right to 0px instead of -31px. Also strictly speaking the OP's question is not really about "responsive" in css world as you stated in your comment, but from the description of the question we know what the OP was trying to achieve and it did work with my answer